# Is it good practice to use V-for inside V-if in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

There is a case where we used:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="fetch">Fetch numbers</button>

    <div v-if="!getNumbers.length">Waiting for numbers...</div>

    <div v-if="getNumbers.length">
      <div v-for="number in getNumbers" :key="number.id">
        <h5>{{ number.owner }}</h5>
        <p>{{ number.phone }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is it a good practice? If not then how can be this improved?

Comment: I don't see why that will be a problem. The thing is, VueJS uses a virtual DOM so all the changes you make at runtime will be bunched/chunked together before writing it out to the actual DOM tree anyway :) the only thing is that [you shouldn't use `v-for` and `v-if` together](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for) (which you're not doing anyway). The only optimization I would suggest is that you use `<template>` for the outer v-if, since you're using the div as simply a placeholder element.

Comment: What about changing the 2nd v-if to v-else?

Comment: Sure. Since you are checking against a boolean, then it makes sense to use `v-else` instead, but that shouldn't change the computational effort behind it.

Comment: I got confused by this part:
The only optimization I would suggest is that you use <template> for the outer v-if since you're using the div as simply a placeholder element. 

Can you show it on code wht you mean?

Comment: Use `<template v-if="getNumbers.length"> ... </template>`, so you don't unnecessary produce a dummy `<div>` element. Or even better, just `<template v-else>`

Comment: Yes but there is a button before v-if

Comment: Also, consider using `keep-alive` directive, to avoid re-rendering every time.

Comment: @NewTechLover That doesn’t change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like you do it is OK.
From style guide of vueJs :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Avoid-v-if-with-v-for-essential